# How to send the Group Notifications using Firebase Cloud messaging?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop the Messenger App like Whatsapp using Firebase.

I'm already done the code for device to device notifications and now I am trying to send the notifications to specified group.

Please provide the example code for the Group Notifications.

Comment: what did you try? show the code and explain please.

Comment: i am using the firebase cloud functions to trigger the database changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to send messages to groups of users:

1. [Send the message to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic) that all [users subscribe to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic). This is the simplest scenario, since you don't need to keep a list of tokens. But you have less control over the actual people that receive the message, as anyone who knows a topic can subscribe to it.
2. Keep a list of device tokens for each group in your app server, and then [send to each individual device in the group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_individual_devices).

   You can also use the previous version of the API to [send to batches of up to 500 tokens at a time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm#send_to_individual_devices). This sort of multicast delivery is not yet possible in the new API.

   For an example of this, see the [documentation of Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) and the [sample repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).
3. [Send to a device group with the legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm#send_to_a_device_group). I'd only recommend this approach if the devices are actually owned by one user, which is the case that device groups are meant for.

Comment: I am using the cloud functions to trigger the database changes

Comment: thanks frank....... but how to collect the all groupMembers tokens from Firebasedb into appserver using Cloud Functions(Node.js)?

Comment: If you're looking for an example, have a look here a https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens and here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/firebase-cloud-messaging-important-rest-apis-be79260022b5)

Don't forget this line Authentication:

```
key=<Your_API_Key>
```

The word (key) is important